# How to reset root password CentOS (domU) hosted in Xen?

Tags: centos, xen, password, root, domu

Need help on resetting root password of a CentOS which is a guess OS (**domU**) in XEN. I already tried to get to grub but it doesn't display or maybe using a different grub (pygrub). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control of the Dom0?

Comment: Please post the DomU-configuration. What XEN-Server ist this, which CentOS-major version, how is the DomU disk configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shut down the guest VM, mount its disk on another VM that you have access to, then manually change the guest's /etc/shadow, or do a chroot to the mounted disk followed by "passwd".

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the parent:

```
xm console $vm
```

Will drop you into the console (can be escaped out of like telnet).

Answer (score 0):

1- Shut down your server using the Xencenter controls

2- Right click on machine and select Properties
3- Go under Boot options 
   Change the OS Boot Parameters to rw init=/bin/bash

Some times for some OS especial CentOS  you will need to write in the field the word single instead of rw init=/bin/bash  so try both if first trick didn’t work.
4- Save and Start your virtual machine

Your system will  boot up in single user mode. So to change your password, you need to type this command:

bash# passwd root

5- Type in your new password you will then be asked to confirm it

Your password has now been reset.

6- Shutdown your virtual machine.
Now go back to the xencenter and startup options and remove rw init=/bin/bash and change it back to whatever was there before. Start up your server and you should be able to logon with your new root password.

Source : http://www.unixmen.com/reset-root-password-linux-vm-hosted-xenserver/